# What does GUILD_VOICE_STATES mean and how to use?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a music player bot and I get the error

`Error [VOICE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Connection not established within 15 seconds`

I found something on this Github page where other people had the same problem https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2979

Someone said that there was a solution with the GUILD_VOICE_STATES. I can not find anything about this. Can someone explain to me what it is and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GUILD_VOICE_STATES` is a [gateway intent](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html), which you can enable via your [`ClientOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions)

```js
// wherever you declare your discord client
const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILD_VOICE_STATES'] } });
```

Comment: In 2022: `const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates] });`