# Bot code seems to fire off before the it even has the chance to get called

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've written some code to check and notify the user that they're not supposed to be using a specific channel if they're not in voice chat. The code is as follows:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv/config')

var guildID = "1128642534483****"

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
    ],
});

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    console.log(1)
    if (message.content !== "") {
        console.log(2)
        if(!message.author.bot) {
            const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID); // Getting the guild.
            const Member = Guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id); // Getting the member.
                if (Member.voice.channel) {
                console.log(`${Member.user.tag} is connected to ${Member.voice.channel.name}!`);
                } 
                if (!Member.voice.channel) {
                console.log(`${Member.user.tag} is not connected.`);
                message.reply({ content: 'This is the voice chat channel.'})
                    .then(msg => {
                setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7500)
                })
            };            
        }             
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

The issue I'm having is that, let's say I join voice chat -> save the code (deploy the node) -> leave voice chat -> then type something, it seems to think I'm still in VC and throws me the 'This is the voice chat channel' message (I believe it's being run on deployment, and then never again).

And it just keeps on returning the same value, regardless of how many times I leave/join VC. I need to restart the node in order to get the bot to actually run the code again.

I must add I'm very new to both JS and Discord.js, I've read a bit on async functions thinking that might've been the issue but I still can't get my head around it. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a caching problem. Notice how you pull both the guild and the member from the cache, e.g. `client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)`. If the cache has not updated since being deployed, your user is still in there as being in the voice channel. I could not find clear information about when exactly the cache is updated, but I suggest that you get the objects via the [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) command:

```
const Guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID); // Getting the guild.
const Member = await client.users.fetch(message.author.id); // Getting the member.
```

Notice how this command is asynchronous, returning a `Promise`, so you must either `await` its completion or use a `.then()` construction like those you are already using.

Edit: As discussed in the comments to this answer, the problem was actually the missing GUILD_VOICE_STATES intent, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573965/what-does-guild-voice-states-mean-and-how-to-use).

Comment: I was really hoping this was it but it seems to still do the same thing despite changing the event function to async as well as using fetch to get these 2 values.

Comment: Maybe it is instead an intents problem. Have you looked into the GUILD_VOICE_STATES intent, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573965/what-does-guild-voice-states-mean-and-how-to-use)?

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that was the issue. I added the intent and it started working perfectly. I was using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637725/user-connected-to-voice-channel) as reference and for some reason, the second code snippet for the accepted answer (Listening to the voiceStateUpdate event) worked even without having to use the GuildVoiceStates intent so I didn't even entertain the idea that I was missing any intents.
Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! I have had my fair share of weird behavior because of missing/wrong intent settings.